# Is there a way to avoid theorem-like environments to be split across pages?

Tags: theorems, typography

In the `article` class, sometimes our definitions or theorems (theorem-like environments) may be split into two parts across two pages. I would like to know if there is a way to avoid this situation to happen without manually clearing the page?

Comment: You could put it into a float: figure, table and create a new one.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Thanks so much for your concern :) If possible, would you mind sharing me with a simple example?

Comment: It might be easier to use the `mdframed` to generate your theorem envs. It can color them etc. But you can then ask it not not add any frames and set it to be unbreakable.

Comment: @daleif: Much appreciated. Would you mind showing me an example? For now I just need the function "making unbreakable".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example using `mdframed`. You will see that the paragraphs on the first page are stretched because the theorem env are not allowed to break.

If it is for a twosided book, the best solution might be to have a system which allows breaking if from a left hand to a right hand page, but not the other way around. I would be surprised if `tcolorbox` didn't have something similar.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

% standard packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,bm}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\mdfdefinestyle{myenvs}{%
  hidealllines=true,%
  nobreak=true, % comment this to allow breaking
  leftmargin=0pt,
  rightmargin=0pt,
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
}

\newmdtheoremenv[style=myenvs]{theorem}{Theorem}


\begin{document}

\kant[1-3]
\begin{theorem}
  \kant[1-2]
\end{theorem}
\kant


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

As @daleif suspected, there is also a `tcolorbox` way to answer the question.

The most basic answer assumes that the OP only wants an existing theorem environment to become unbreakable. Lets name this environment `theorem`. It is made unbreakable by:

```
\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{blanker,before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt}
```

The skip values can be adapted as needed.
The complete proposed answer is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{plain}% from amsthm
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}% from amsthm

\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{blanker,before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{theorem}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Of course, there is a plethora of ways to make the box colorful and fancy, if needed. Also, `tcolorbox` provides own theorem environments, but this is another story.

For completeness: `mdframed` has the same mechanism with `\surroundwithmdframed` to patch an existing environment. You can flip a coin which package to use for this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Without the figure, it would have been split across pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{figure}[thb]
\begin{thm}
\lipsum[5-6]
\end{thm}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[7-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks; but when I use [thb] then the words inside the theorem block get smaller?

Comment: They stand for Top, Here, Bottom of page.

Comment: Using a float might send theorems far away, not really a good idea. And `h` does not mean *here*, but rather *here if possible*

Comment: @dateif, would you prefer to use \vfil and a minipage?

Comment: You will have to do it by hand, which is annoying.